# Link existing docker to external configuration file and data to be used it in C# core (linux container)

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, environment-variables, configuration-files

I am writing in C# core, using linux container (running in windows).

I need a way to use external configuration file, **and a way in programming (C# core code) to get the values of the configuration file**.

That's without copy the docker configuration file into the image, used by:

```
docker cp ...
```

Need that for an existing container, without need to rebuild or run a new container instance for that (only by using the existing container).

Also, I need to map a volume to an existing container, without the need to rebuild or run a new container.

The following command is not suitable, since it creates a new container instance:

```
docker run -v ...
```

Need also a way to read some specific enviornment variables in C# core language, after use it as:

```
docker run -e ...
```

**Is there any best practice for above?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is extremely normal to need to delete and recreate containers.  For instance, if you have a new build of your application, you’ll need to delete and recreate any containers that are running it to run against the new image.  You can’t add a volume mapping to an existing container; but recreating containers should be so routine that it shouldn’t be a big deal to recreate it with the new volume mapping.

Using `docker run -v` as a path to inject config files into a container is pretty normal.  You can store it at a fixed path in the container, and use whatever config-file-parsing library you have readily available to read it.  It can be anywhere on the host, but it’s fine to have a fixed value for the right-hand side of the `docker run -v` option.

(The two other good things to use bind-mounted volumes for are getting log files out of a container, and storage of persistent data that lives in the filesystem but must outlive a single container instance.)

Comment: I don't know if what I said is possible. If it is indeed possible - why not? It is a good idea to map a volume with config file. The only choice I see, is to use docker cp, and that;s how I am using the existing container. Another issue, i.e is rabbit-mq that is on specific compiter in the network, and on specific container. it may be changed from time to time. When it is changed - I want to resolve its container IP and send it to the other container. How can I do it in the best practice way? Is there any best practice to participate configuration file (the configuration file may also change).

Comment: Also, I don't know what can I write in C# core, to use that variables (supplied by -v or -e), even I run a new container instance.

Comment: Docker provides a DNS service for inter-container communication.  You never directly need the docker-internal IP addresses for anything.

Comment: So, if i.e a rabbit-mq is on a docker. How can I connect that rabbit-mq of program in another docker in the same computer (or other computer)? Can you give me any example, please.

Comment: As I said for the other docker (rabbit-mq) - I have the tag name and the ip of the computer that running the docker. How can I find in C# core code the other docker ip? Need an example, please.

Comment: You cannot reach the Docker-internal IP on the other system.  Use the other system’s IP address and the port you published there with `docker run -p`.

Comment: So how can I reach the rabbit-mq, which is on other container and other computer?